# How can I make a system that will check whether the text I write in the textbox exists in the sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a very simple question because I am very new and trying to learn. I want to create a text box on my own website and write a system that checks whether what is written in that box is in google sheets and says to the user whether it exists or not.

I dont know where should i start.

Comment: You can start by creating a basic HTML form with a text input box and a submit button. Then you can use JavaScript to fetch the value of the text box when the submit button is clicked, and send a request to Google Sheets API to check if the value exists in the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an example but and you can change it in the way you want.

```
let mainData = "this is our main string data...";
let inputString = "this in my entered val";
        
        
let result = mainData.includes(inputString);
```